# `SELECT UNION SELECT` query with independent ORDER BY sorting?

Tags: sql, mariadb, union

I've got two queries I want to merge together for ease of progressing the results on the backend.

The basic structure is:

```
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.field DESC, table.timestamp DESC)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.timestamp DESC)
```

There are `WHERE` clauses I'm omitting which cause these queries to return totally different results but in the same form. The problem is nothing I add to the `ORDER BY` will change it's sorting, and it is not sorting correctly. In fact both groups seem to be sorting backwards. But even if I try to sort by an unrelated numeric field, the orders do not change.

Maybe `UNION` is not what I want here? Is there a 'dumber' way to lump two SQL results together?

I do NOT want the entire merged result set to have the same sorting. I'm trying to get a list with special/important items at the top, then other items in certain time frames shown below, sorted by date/time.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih They're just rows that are not actually being sorted by what I put in the ORDER BY clause. They appear to be being ordered by the timestamp, ascending (or their ID, which will result in the same order) The union seems to be nullifying the ORDER BY.

Comment: @l008com - Correct deduction.  (My Answer explains Why.)  What version of MariaDB are you using?

Answer (score 2):

**The "Why"**:  A subquery, by definition, returns an unordered set of row.   The Optimizer only recently started taking advantage of that clause in the Standard.  In doing so, it tosses the `ORDER BY` (unless there is a `LIMIT`; See Plan A).  The order you saw was just coincidence based perhaps on the index used to satisfy the `WHERE`.  To properly sort the results you must apply some ordering afterward (see Plans B).

Another recent optimization...  Previously, a `UNION` *always* fed the results from each subquery into a temp table.  Now, in the case of `UNION ALL` (and a few other restrictions), it can feed the results directly to the client.  (However, my suggested Plans B and C will still need a temp in order to perform the `ORDER BY`.)

**Plan A** is a kludge that *might* work:

```
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.field DESC, table.timestamp DESC
                     LIMIT 9999999)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.timestamp DESC
                     LIMIT 9999999)
```

**Plan B** may work, depending on whether the `ORDER BY` can fit with the data:

```
(SELECT * FROM table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM table)
ORDER BY table.field DESC, table.timestamp DESC
```

**Plan C** is an attempt to generalize on Plan B:

```
(SELECT *, 1 AS seq1, table.field AS seq2 FROM table)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *, 2 AS seq1, 0 AS seq2 FROM table)
ORDER BY seq1,           -- to get the first SELECT first
         seq2 DESC,      -- unclear what your intent was with table.field
         timestamp DESC
```

**Bottom Line**. To get an order, you must explicitly have `ORDER BY`.  (Currently, you are depending on `UNION` pieces being done sequentially.  *Some* day, `UNIONs` may be done in parallel.)

Comment: Thanks Rick, the Planc C is what I needed in my case

Answer (score 1):

I know it's ugly but try:

```
select a.* from (
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.field DESC, table.timestamp DESC)
) a
UNION ALL
select b.* from (
(SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.timestamp DESC)
) b
```

Note: I assume you are aware that you will get duplicate results with Union

Comment: Queries are kind of opposites so there won't be any duplicates anyway.

Comment: Ok cool. In terms of ordering each subquery independently, this definitely works, I just tested it

Comment: Cool ill try it out when I get a chance. Just looking at it, Its not clear what it does, that my more basic form does not do. Or to put it another way, what is wrong with my original query? Seems like it's right.

Comment: ACK! I just implemented this and no change. I'm still getting a fixed ascending order I cannot change :(

Comment: That's weird, I tested your original query and then tested it like this, the original one doesn't sort and this one does - not sure why it's not working for you. Your timestamp field is stored as a datetime object and not a varchar right?

Comment: @Matt - For the same reason (see my answer), the Optimizer will be free to ignore the `ORDER BY` in those derived tables.  So, I _expect_ this technique to fail (at least on newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB).  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you can try to make a `grp` column in subquery to represent two result `order by` order.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,1 grp 
    FROM table 
    ORDER BY 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *,2 
    FROM table 
) t1
ORDER BY t1.grp,t1.field DESC, t1.timestamp DESC
```

Comment: The extra layer is not necessary.  (See my Plan C.)  However, parentheses are desired.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `where` conditions in the `order by`.  Something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where (<1>) or (<2>)
order by (<1>) desc,  -- put the "1" rows first
         (case when <1> then t.field desc end),
         t.timestamp asc;
```

Comment: This assumes the two `SELECTs` are really coming from the same `table`.  (I figure the OP over-simplified the query, and really it is two different tables?)

Comment: @RickJames . . . Nothing in the question suggests they are different tables.  The use of `select *` and the identical `from` clauses both suggest they are from the same table.

Comment: Perhaps the `and` should be changed to `OR` in the `WHERE`?

Answer (score 0):

Inside order cluser dont effect to output result. 
You must use Order Out Of union.

```
SELECT * From (
SELECT * FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table
) as T Order by T.field  DESC ,table.timestamp DESC
```